# Yii2, How can I set several values to a same attribute?

Tags: php, yii2

I would like to set a default filter to my gridview and I am not sure how.

I have this:

```
public function actionIndex()
    {

        $searchModel = new SearchParque();
        $searchModel->parada = 0;
        if (User::getCurrentUser()['username']=='vlc') {
            $searchModel->Provincia_Id = 10;
        }

       $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

       return $this->render('index', [
            'searchModel' => $searchModel,
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        ]);
    }
```

I want that `Provincia_Id` to have several values for a default filter. 
Example the `Provincia_Id` has 10 as a value but also has 7.
Any Help?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a new field ProvinciaIds to SearchParque class, add array validation rule for it, assign an array [10,7] to it in controller and add `->andFilterWhere(["Provinca_Id" => $this->ProvinciaIds])` to the query in search model. Use this field in search form view instead of Provincia_Id.